# How to hide detail view labels on yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to hide labels for the detail view

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        //To hide labels
        'label' => ['hidden' => true],
        'attributes' => [
             'visits'

        ],
    ]) ?>
```

On the above snipet of code, there is 'label' => ['hidden' => true], is there but it is not a method which is existing. I want to know is there a method to hide labels Something which is equivalent to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide label column in GridView you must modify its [enter link description here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-detailview#$template-detail)template. For example:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'template' => '<tr><td{contentOptions}>{value}</td></tr>',
    'attributes' => [
        // your attributes for displaying
    ],
]) ?>
```

If you want to hide a label in one cell you can set an empty string to `label` property:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'template' => '<tr><td{contentOptions}>{value}</td></tr>',
    'attributes' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'id',
            'label' => ''
        ]
        // your attributes for displaying
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: On the question i just want to hide the id can you modify the code accordingly?

Comment: Do you want to hide ID label or ID label with data?

Comment: Only id label I want the data of id to be visible

Comment: I am getting this error The attribute must be specified in the format of "attribute", "attribute:format" or "attribute:format:label"

Comment: Yeah mycode i forget [] thank you i accepted the answer

Comment: There is one more problem i am using discription:html in one of column if i use the above code it is saying in at this way getting Unknown property ::discription:html

Comment: I am running across a new issue now can you please have a look on the same?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53960666/unknown-property-yii-base-unknownpropertyexception-discriptionhtml

Comment: @ArunVM I answered this question