# Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException ::discription:html

Tags: php, yii2

This is the continuation of this question [How to hide detail view labels on yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53959698/how-to-hide-detail-view-labels-on-yii2/)

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'template' => '<tr><td{contentOptions}>{value}</td></tr>',
        'attributes' => [
          [
            'attribute' => 'discription:html',

            'label' => ''
          ]
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

The description is supposed to render in HTML only So the above code is but if I use the above code I am ending up in at this error. Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each attribute may has [own settings](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-detailview#$attributes-detail) which might be configured in attribute array. For example, you can configure the data format like:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'discription',
            'format' => 'html'
            'label' => ''
        ]
    ],
]) ?>
```